# Angular Velocity measured by a UGV on a curved path is equivalent to Angular velocity of UGV on a straight path

Tags: acceleration, angular-velocity, electronics, gyroscopes

**Pre-Condition**

An FOG IMU is mounted on a high speed Autonomous Vehicle to track linear acceleration and angular velocity of the vehicle under dynamic conditions, Here FOG Z axis (accelerometer + gyroscope) points towards the sky and X axis (accelerometer + gyroscope) points towards the front of the vehicle and Y axis (accelerometer + gyroscope) points towards the left side of the vehicle.

The IMU is fixed at the center of the vehicle

**Question**

I was trying to record centripetal acceleration captured by the accelerometers by moving the vehicle on a curved path wherein I observed a strange phenomenon,

During this motion I observed,
Angular velocity measured in the Yaw or Z axis of gyroscope is similar to Angular Velocity Measured by the IMU when vehicle is moving on a straight path.

I am unable to understand as to why the gyroscope would pick up angular velocity while moving on a straight path whose magnitude is equivalent to when the same vehicle is moving on a curved path.

Kindly guide me through the principle as I think I am missing something basic.

Thanks for helping me out !!